Running docker container but won't show website in localhost
Very new to Docker! I have a website running in asp.net which works perfectly when running the app locally but when I run it off a docker container it returns a 404 error.
When I run the app off docker it successfully sets up an image and runs a container but when I visit the localhost it returns a 404 error. So I went on to postman to see what the api returned when the container was running and that also returned a 404 error.
Here is my docker file:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ReactJS App/ReactJS App.csproj", "ReactJS App/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ReactJS App/ReactJS App.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ReactJS App"
RUN dotnet build "ReactJS App.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ReactJS App.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ReactJS App.dll"]

Visiting either of these returns a 404 error.

I have seen some other posts on this and followed their instructions but the app still isn't running off Docker. Could this be because I am running a postgresql database locally which isn't being reached in the container?

Which port are you connecting to from Postman and what URL? 404 means that something is responding, but the URL can't be found.

Looks like there's a problem with your publishing. How about running it in vs2022 via docker ?

Hi I am connecting the the port in the picture above https://localhost:32780/

I am running it off vs2022 via docker
